# TensorFlow, Julia // Node name already exists in the Graph

Tags: tensorflow, julia

I'm using TensorFlow with Julia and I would like to reduce an expression with the following:

```
cross_entropy = nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( logits, labels) 

optimizer = train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)

train_op = train.minimize(optimizer,reduce_mean(cross_entropy))
```

I have the following error:

```
 ERROR: Tensorflow error: Status: Node name 'gradients/reduce_grad/Reshape' already exists in the Graph

Stacktrace:
 [1] check_status at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:459 [inlined]
 [2] import_graph_def(::TensorFlow.Graph, ::Array{UInt8,1}, ::TensorFlow.GraphImportOptions) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:1680
 [3] import_graph_def(::TensorFlow.Graph, ::TensorFlow.tensorflow.GraphDef, ::TensorFlow.GraphImportOptions) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:1690
 [4] extend_graph(::TensorFlow.Graph, ::Array{Any,1}) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:427
 [5] extend_graph(::Array{Any,1}) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:291
 [6] gradients(::TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Void) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:1583
 [7] gradients(::TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32}, ::Array{Any,1}) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:1575
 [8] compute_gradients(::TensorFlow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer, ::TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32}, ::Void) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/train.jl:48
 [9] #minimize#1(::Void, ::Void, ::Void, ::Function, ::TensorFlow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer, ::TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32}) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/train.jl:40
 [10] minimize(::TensorFlow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer, ::TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32}) at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/train.jl:37
```

In python, there is an instruction to avoid the error: `tf.reset_default_graph()` but there is not the similar command in Julia, I asked it to GitHub: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/374

Can you help me ?

**EDIT**

Sometimes, I have this warning about the python version. I upgraded the version with the indicated commands, but it did not work. Maybe the problem is here ?

```
WARNING: Your Python TensorFlow client version (1.5.0) is below the TensorFlow backend version (1.6.0). This can cause various errors. Please upgrade your Python TensorFlow installation and then restart Julia.
You can upgrade by calling `using Conda; Conda.update();` from Julia.
```

Here is my code:

```
ENV["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0" # It is to use the GPU

using TensorFlow
using Distributions

rng = MersenneTwister(1235) 

function weight_variable(shape)
   initial = map(Float32, rand(Normal(0, .001), shape...))
   return Variable(initial)
end

function bias_variable(shape)
   initial = fill(Float32(.1), shape...)
   return Variable(initial)
end


# Inputs

num_pixels = 12

num_classes = 10

x = placeholder(Float32, shape=[nothing, num_pixels])

Weight = weight_variable([num_pixels,num_classes]) 

biases = bias_variable([num_classes]) 

logits = x*Weight  + biases

labels = rand(rng,0:9,10) # Random labels for the test

cross_entropy = nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( logits = logits, labels = labels)


cross_entropy_reduce = reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

optimizer = train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)

train_op = train.minimize(optimizer,cross_entropy_reduce) # Here is the crash
```

I use atom for IDE, with julia 0.6.2.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a MWE, that can be executed to get your error

Comment: I edited my post with my code...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The above runs fine on my machine.

Comment: So, I add the stacktrace and a warning I have sometimes when I run a program... Maybe there are some informations with it.

Comment: Here is the explanation of MWE,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
I would be surprised if this was minimal. Please provide smaller code that reproduces the error. (By making the MWE you may discover yourself what is wrong.)

Comment: Ok, here is the minimum code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem with this example:

```
using TensorFlow

sess = Session(Graph())
W = Variable([1.0, 1.0])
loss = nn.l2_loss(W)
optimizer = train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train_step = train.minimize(optimizer, loss) # crash
```

It seems to be a version problem. TensorFlow 1.5 and 1.6 are failing with the same error as you have. But with TensorFlow 1.4.0 it works fine. I also tried your example and all looks good.

Make sure, the fourth and fifth line in the file /home/name/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/deps/build.jl are

```
const cur_version = "1.4.0"
const cur_py_version = "1.4.0"
```

and rebuild the package with `Pkg.build("TensorFlow")` in the julia command line. 
If it does not work, you can try to remove and reinstall the package.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but it does not work...  I have the same error.   When I tried to reinstall the package, it said it don't know the package TensorFlow (the spelling was correct, I checked it)... So, I paste my save package in .julia then I rebuild with the version 1.4.0

Comment: My problem is the configuration: I configured all with the TensorFlow 1.6. So, I download the version 1.4.0 and restart the configuration (with ./configure). But I can't compile the file libtensorflow.so in the folder tensorflow-v1.4.0 (Normally, I paste this file in .julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/deps/usr/bin) Following that, I can't use my gpu and change the configuration...